# Scrolling in chrome shears text and elements

Tags: theming

the testing version of a portfolio site I'm working on started behaving strangely in the past few days. This might or might not be a problem related to drupal itself, but I've never come across this on a non-drupal project.

http://beta.mattgrossdesign.com/about

On my Win7 machine, Chrome 36, scrolling the page causes all the fixed position elements to be rendered in multiple places or sheared off.

Image Reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSvjq.jpg

Firefox & IE aren't having problems, any ideas?

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` to your fixed elements.

Comment: I tried to inject this through Chrome and everything works fine. You are missing something.

Comment: Caching in pre-production will be the death of me.

You sir take the cake.